# Vim Formatter vs VsCode Formatter Problem with GIT

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, formatting, plugin-coc, vscode

I am using Vim (neovim) for the past couple of weeks now.
I am facing one problem with the way vim formats the code.
My other team members uses vscode which formats JS file on Save something like this:

```
function test(test,test){
  const {getter,setter} = dummyObj;
}
```

The above code gets formated into:

```
function test(test, test) { // Notice the space between params
  const { getter, setter } = dummyObj; // Notice the space between destructed variables
}
```

And Vim does exactly the opposite, which is on save file it removes any spaces between params and etc.

So when I save a file in nvim if that was saved in Vscode earlier it will now format by my nvim. And these changes will be counted as modification in GIT

Does anybody notice or encounter this issue? How you are tacking it?

The plugin I am using is:
**coc-vim**

and I have added auto-format on save the file in coc-vim configuration file:

```
{
    "suggest.noselect": false,
    "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": [
        "javascript",
        "typescript",
        "json"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is "being formatted"? When? How? Does it occur with clean configuration?

Comment: @Matt Sorry to miss that information, "Code" is being formated on "Save" The settings  I have made to format on saving is in "coc.vim" configuration

Comment: Coc recommends using coc-tsserver (https://github.com/neoclide/coc-tsserver#configuration-options). [It's unclear how the formatting takes place](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/6cc7432fa00d8a7351cee54f7b800e992057315a/doc/coc.txt#L767), but I suspect it's an LSP request? cf. https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/6cc7432fa00d8a7351cee54f7b800e992057315a/doc/coc.txt#L1862

Comment: Do you have [coc-prettier](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-prettier) installed? If not, maybe try installing it? If you do, then maybe look at the GitHub docs to look into how to configure it...

Comment: Thank you for the comment @filbranden, Yes I think I need to check more on coc plugin and configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue with the following:

*Note: First thing if you are new to vim, neovim do check your settings and prettier settings for the project.*

To solve this issue, first I check with my project requirements in terms of prettier and how and what formatting my project requires. Based on that I have installed `coc-prettier` plugging and added required rules in `coc-settings.json` like the followings:

```
{   
    
    "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
    "prettier.semi": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 2
}
```

After this as well I was facing some issues with arrowParens. Like even it is specified that arrow parans should be avoided in case of single params, somehow `coc-prettier` was picking up settings from somewhere in the project and applying opposite of the rule.

So to tackle this I have added my own `.prettierrc` in the project root, which is put in `.gitignore`, and added a rule to overwrite arraowparans behavior as expected.

With these settings, I am able to get to a place where 99% of required formatting by my project is handled by neovim now

I said 99% because I am still facing one issue:
In case of importing functions using destructor in multiline format like:

```
const {
  fooFunction,
  foo2Function
} = require('./fooModule');
```

The Prettier / Formatter formats this in one line like this:

```
const { fooFunction, foo2Function } = require('./fooModule');
```

because of this, the existing code base having such formatting changes.

But I think I can live with it until I get any solution.

For more information on settings, you check out following links:

https://github.com/neoclide/coc-prettier
https://gist.github.com/sidgujrathi/5e60ba7faf677d550264456ca37e3f32
https://gist.github.com/sidgujrathi/77ac41b72bab472bfbe1762c423ca5fd